# Qt5 Quick Application Window not shown on Windows

Tags: windows, qt5

The program runs fine on Linux. The program also runs fine when started inside QtCreator on both, debug and release. There are no hints that any part of the qml files were missing.

Now when I run windeployqt for this executable, a lot of files are copied to the destination dir. But when I start the program, it only appears in the task manager. No window is shown.

First I thought it has seomthing to do with the QtCharts module, which is used inside. But creating a new project, the output seems to be fine after compiling, after running windeployqt even QtCreator tells me 
"QtQuick.Window" not installed
"QtQuick.Dialogs" not installed
"QtQuick" not installed

So - what exactly is going on here? Is it possible to deploy a QtQuick application on Windows at all?

Comment: Try to use the qmldir parameter. Sounds like a common deployment issue: something is missing, either Qml files or DLLs.

Comment: Very cool, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not forget some additional parameters you may need to specify while using windeployqt. Have a look [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

- use `--qmldir <directory>` option
- have a look at your pro file and add every module you are using. For example if you have `QT += quick widgets qml` then add these options `-qml -quick -widgets`

Comment: Yes, the problem was indeed that I called windeployqt in the release directory, so it could not know where to search for the qml files.
I did not know that it has to know about them.

Comment: My `windeployqt` command line was missing the `-qml -quick -widgets -quickwidgets` parameters. The `--qmldir` option was enough for `Debug` (the `QT*` folders were copied), but not for `Release`.